How to get id of elemenet from FormControl
Hay
I have input select with label(value) and key(id)
whan I click on submit I want to get key(id)
<form (submit)="onSubmit(testForm)" [formGroup]="form">

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="text" name="user" [formControlName]="username" id="userid" required>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

//I expect to receive [id] value form.controls.username ... id

Your description and code don't match. There is no select with label / value and key / id. There is only an input type text.

You have to use property binding for the [value] and ensure you set the key for it.
You are not supposed to use required since it works better with template driven forms, instead use Validators.required.
Also prefer (ngSubmit) instead of (submit).
Docs for reactive forms
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
  <input
    matInput
    type="text"
    name="user"
    formControlName="username"
    id="userid"
  />
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="food">
      @for (food of foods; track food) {
      <mat-option [value]="food.value">{{food.viewValue}}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  form = new FormGroup({
    food: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });
  foods: Food[] = [
    { value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
    { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
    { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' },
  ];

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
